# How to bind an event to mouse wheel click (not scroll) in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to bind an event to mouse wheel click (not scroll) in Tkinter?

I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *


def callback(_event=None):
    print("Mouse wheel was clicked!")

root = Tk()
root.bind("<MouseWheel>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

But it reacts on the mouse wheel movement (not click).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mousewheel button is seen as just another mouse button. I think for most systems it is `<Button-3>`, but it could be different on different systems (eg: `<Button-2>`, `<Button-4>`).

```
root.bind("<Button-3>", callback)
```

Comment: PS: In my case the right button was <Button-2> (Windows 10)